# Pub get failed & errors in dependencies (Flutter Retrieve Markers From Firestore in Flutter app)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, backend, google-maps-markers

I am newbie in app development and follow the tutorial as below:

1. Firebase project setup & create database in firestore :
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NO-F6fhQow&list=PLgGjX33Qsw-Ha_8ks9im86sLIihimuYrr&index=13
2. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctOcXmUZOZo

The debug got zero problem. But the message below is shown when running the app :

```
Because firebase_core >=1.10.6 depends on firebase_core_web ^1.5.3 which depends on flutter_web_plugins any from sdk, firebase_core >=1.10.6 requires flutter_web_plugins any from sdk.
So, because flutter_web_plugins from sdk doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_web_plugins in the Flutter SDK) and googlemap depends on firebase_core ^1.11.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 6 in 32 seconds...
```

What I had tried for troubleshooting server unavailable:
- built VPN
- check network connectivity
- ping dart.dev.com

And also, here is the current dependencies :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  firebase_core: ^1.11.0
  cloud_firestore: 
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

However, the error remains, how to interpret the error message correctly ?

Comment: here is the update. the error change to this (after switch the device to mobile & add '''flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter''' in dependency ) : '''Because googlemap depends on flutter_web_plugins any from sdk which doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_web_plugins in the Flutter SDK), version solving failed.'''

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.